# Remove alphanumeric word from string

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

I am trying to remove alphanumeric word from string..

```
 String[] sentenceArray= {"India123156 hel12lo 10000 cricket 21355 sport news 000Fifa"};
    for(String s: sentenceArray)
        {
            String finalResult = new String();
            String finalResult1 = new String();
            String str= s.toString();
            System.out.println("before regex : "+str);
            String regex = "(\\d?[,/%]?\\d|^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)";
            finalResult1 = str.replaceAll(regex, " ");
            finalResult = finalResult1.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");
            System.out.println("after regex : "+finalResult);
        }
```

output: hel lo cricket sport news Fifa

but my required output is: cricket sport news

Guys please help..
Thank you in advance

Comment: FYI added demo and explanation. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match the words you want to exclude and the following space characters, you can use the following regex in case-insensitive mode ([demo](http://regex101.com/r/kE9cS0)):

```
\b(?=[a-z]*\d+)\w+\s*\b
```

In Java, to replace this, you can do:

```
String replaced = your_original_string.replaceAll("(?i)\\b(?=[a-z]*\\d+[a-z]*)\\w+\\s*\\b", "");
```

**Token-by-Token Explanation**

```
\b                       # the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                         # something that is not a word char
(?=                      # look ahead to see if there is:
  [a-z]*                 #   any character of: 'a' to 'z' (0 or more
                         #   times (matching the most amount
                         #   possible))
  \d+                    #   digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                         #   the most amount possible))
)                        # end of look-ahead
\w+                      # word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                         # more times (matching the most amount
                         # possible))
\s*                      # whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                         # more times (matching the most amount
                         # possible))
\b                       # the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                         # something that is not a word char
```

Comment: What this regex `(?i)` means?

Comment: `(?i)` turns on the case-insensitive flag. It means that `[a-z]` for instance can match not only lowercase letters, but `ALSO UPPERCASE`. :)

Comment: Another way to turn on the flag is to add `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` as an argument when you compile the regex, but I and many others who work with regex find `(?i)` more clear because it is right in front of your eyes.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "India123156 hel12lo 10000 cricket 21355 sport news 000Fifa";
    // String s = "cricket abc";
    // cricket sport news
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\b\\w+?[0-9]+\\w+?\\b", "").trim());

}
```

O/P :

```
cricket  sport news

Explaination :

\\b --> word boudry i.e, it marks the beginning and end of a word..
\\w+ -->one or more alphabets . 
\\w+?[0-9] --> Zero or one occurance of (one or more alphabets) followed by one or more digits.
\\w+?--> ending with  Zero or one occurance of (one or more alphabets) and marked by word boundry.
trim() --> removing leading and trailing whitespaces.
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj - explained :)

Comment: @AvinashRaj - yes..My bad. you could replace it with [a-zA-Z]. I've a habit of using \\w+ :) and also [0-9] could be repalce with \\d+.